# regex to match list of characters and specific words

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex username whitelist allowing a specific list of characters and specific list of words (html entities)

This is the current regex that I have `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.@\|:()\[\]%_\/'-]+$` but I would also want to allow `&amp;` but I have no idea how to join the two

https://regex101.com/r/t0GmKe/1/

Comment: You can use `$amp;` in an alternation `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.@\|:()\[\]%_\/'-]|&amp;)+$` https://regex101.com/r/qQg5B6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternation:

```regex
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.@\|:()\[\]%_\/'-]|&amp;)+$
```

This simply says to match a character from your current character class or `&amp;`, one or more times.